# React Native Navigation adding multiple screens in the background

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to do some deep linking so that when a user gets a push notification to go to their chat screen. I can get to the correct screen, though I was wondering if there is a good way to silently add other screens underneath.

The reason behind this is that our app has a structure where to get to the chat screen you have to have the home screen and then conversation screen and the chat and conversation screen both have a back button. Without the correct navigation stack the back button could get the user into a weird state.

Comment: To clarify... The user can click the notification to jump straight to the chat screen... Then from there the user can click back button to navigate backwards?

Comment: @SGhaleb correct

Answer (score 1):

So after some digging for redux there is a reset function that you can call to reset and build the stack as you want. I was able to set the stack correctly by using the [NavigationActions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html) to build the new stack and index to point to the correct route.

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

dispatch({
    index: 2,
    key: null,
    type: 'Navigation/RESET',
    actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'PotentialMatches' }),
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Conversations' }),
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Chat' }),
    ],
})
```